# Creating a Swift app using Mongodb atlas and realm

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm, mongodb-atlas

I am a relativley new to app development. I am currently using Swift to create a new app. I am using Mongodb realm as my database with the atlas cluster. My main issue is being able to connect my app to the mongodb atlas cluster. I am able to add new users, and it appears on my realm app, but I'm not sure how to create and add a new user to the atlas cluster. I think the way to go is using the mongodb swift driver that mongodb has created, but I am having issues installing that package. I am just truly lost on what I need to do to connect my swift app to the atlas cluster to where I can see in the atlas cluster the various data inputs a user would give in the swift app (stuff like email, first name, last name, etc...) Any advice on steps I should do would be appreciated. Here is the code that may be useful in diagnosing my issue:

[Realm code to add new user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIALE.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You don't need to add users to the Atlas cluster, or really do *anything* with Atlas other than the initial setup. The MongoDB Realm SDK in XCode is where you should be doing all of your work; creating your objects, getting data, performing queries etc. If you want to see 'data inputs a user would give' that's something you create in your app, which is backed by Realm objects. Do you have a specific coding question we may be able to help you with? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't really have a coding question. It's my first time using mongodb and realm, and coding in Swift, so I'm just trying to figure everything out. Is there a way I can see user input in the mongodb website. For instance, in the atlas cluster, we can see data that users input through the mongodb website. Is there a such thing for Realm? I can currently see use input data through the Realm Studios, but that's only on a local machine, what about info that is sent to the cloud, how can I see that?

Comment: MongoDB Realm Sync is backed by Atlas. So if you log into your [MongoDB Console](https://account.mongodb.com/account/login) you can then go to Clusters in the left column (which is selected by Default) and then click the Collections button on the right. That will show all of your collections and the (Realm) data they contain. If you want to work directly with your Realm configuration, users, rules etc, click the Realm button at the top and select your app. Remember MongoDB Realm funnels your Apps data into Atlas so it's viewable (and edible) in Atlas like any other Mongo database.

Comment: For some reason, whenever I add a new user, it is recognized in the Realm app, but not in the Atlas cluster. I have everything synced and I am in development mode, but whenever I add a new user, it is not added to the atlas collection that I have created for users. The atlas cluster constantly has "Query resuts: 0" no matter how many users I add. In my code, I used the .add function that realm provides to add the user. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I will edit my question so that I can show the code.

Comment: That's correct. Realm Users are handled by Realm, not by Atlas. Console->Realm->click your app, then App Users in the left column. If you have extra data you want to store about users, you need to create a User class in realm, populate it and store it.

Comment: Could you go into depth when you say "create a User class in Realm." How do I do that?

Comment: It's a just a Realm object to store extra user data. There are examples in the Realm docs [Define a Realm Object Schema - iOS SDK](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/define-a-realm-object-model/#std-label-ios-define-a-realm-object-schema). In your use case, instead of a Dog object, you would call it `User` object and store information in it's properties about the user; where they are located, their favorite food or their shoe size for example. It's also best practice to store the users uid as one of the properties so that can be used to get that object when they sign in.